# How to build a homepage android application?

Tags: android, layout

I would like to know how this homepage from Google Docs app is build ?
Is there Multiple relative layout to display inline buttons?
And what about the tab bar at the top ?

Image :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that is made of:

1 Header : Horizontal LinearLayout
2 Lines : 2 Horizontal LinearLayouts included into one Vertical LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/header_gradient" >

        <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_layout_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:text="Docs"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_layout_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_add"
                android:src="@drawable/add"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_search"
                android:src="@drawable/search"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView android:id="image_1" />
        <ImageView android:id="image_2" />
        <ImageView android:id="image_3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line_2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView android:id="image_4" />
        <ImageView android:id="image_5" />
        <ImageView android:id="image_6" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works great ! But I had to add  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" on each element, otherwise they weren't display, do u know why ?

Comment: Yes, I just made this code in a few sec, so I assume this is not perfect. Android requires a width and a height on each element.